# Is there a CLI command for adding properties to an existing Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Just out of sheer laziness, I'm interested in knowing whether there's a command that will allow me to add a single field to an existing Doctrine entity, using prompts similar to the ones that appear when I run `doctrine:generate:entity`. Does such a command exist?

(For now, I'll go ahead and manually add my property, getters and setters in the entity's PHP file. I'm just curious about whether there's a CLI way to do it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. If you are using Syfmony 3.x or Symfony 4 you can install the symfony maker bundle (`composer require symfony/maker-bundle`).

Then, you can run the command `php bin/console make:entity` and select an existing entity name. It will detect that is created and allow you to add fields dynamically.

UPDATE: And it's not laziness. Code generation tools save time in repetitive tasks and allow you to focus more on your business logic. :)

Answer (score -2):

No there isn't a command to add a new property to an existing entity because is no sense to do it I think.
For example if you want to add a new property you can add simply into the entity file and after you can launch the command to generate getter and setter.

Add a new property to an existing entity is very easy but it's not possible with a command.

Another way could be to use migration but you don't do it all by the CLI.

So the answer is:
if you want to add a new property add it into the entity file and after generate getter and setter